# gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() is null when reload the page

Tags: javascript, google-api

gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() become null after page reload. So while signing out an error coming. How to fix this?

```
function signOut() {
    try{
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        });
    }catch(e){console.log(e)}

}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: yes i got solution

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="g-signin2"></div>
```

add this code on same page where is logout button ,i was face same issue when i add this one my problem was solved